# Problems when adding empty Azure disk

Tags: powershell, azure, addition, disk, powershell-cmdlet

Using Azure powershell cmdlets, for an already existing VM called "raytest-ze1-06".  I am attempting to add an empty storage disk to a different storage account than the VM was created on, but I am receiving a very strange error from Azure:

```
PS C:\> Get-AzureVM -ServiceName "cse1dmzinfracorep01" -Name "raytest-ze1-06" | Add-AzureDataDisk -CreateNew -DiskSizeInGB 10 -DiskLabel "fourth" -LUN 1 -MediaLocation "https://sae1excdmzcore2.blob.core.windows.net/ddisk1/raytest-ze1-01-dd1-1.vhd" | Update-AzureVM

VERBOSE: 2:22:40 PM - Completed Operation: Get Deployment 
VERBOSE: 2:22:42 PM - Completed Operation: Get Deployment 
VERBOSE: 2:22:42 PM - Begin Operation: Update-AzureVM 
Update-AzureVM : InternalError : The server encountered an internal error. 

Please retry the request. 
At line:1 char:243 
+ ... 1-dd1-1.vhd" | Update-AzureVM 
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Update-AzureVM], CloudException

    + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceManagement.IaaS.UpdateAzureVMCommand

VERBOSE: 2:23:15 PM - Completed Operation: Update-AzureVM
```

I have tried many things, but cannot get it to add the disk.  If I switch the default storage account for my subscription back to the storage account the VM was created on, (and change the medialocation to reflect appropriate container) it works fine.

Comment: Can you please try adding disk using azure portal and check its working. Powershell leads to adding disk to default storage account if medialocation is not defined explicitly. Portal adds drive to the same storage where the vm is and not in default storage.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you cannot add a disk that is on a different storage account. The disks have to be on the same storage account as the VM is.

To get the maximum performance out of the disks, you can follow a guide similar to how you optimize for a SQL server load found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn133149.aspx).

Lastly, you can find all the limits for the storage accounts (and other Azure services) [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/azure-subscription-service-limits/)